# About gRPC Capacity/Adjustment

Tags: java, microservices, grpc, grpc-java

I am running a micro service using gRPC, and got many onError() call-backs on the client side from the server.

t.printStackTrace() shows:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:385)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:339)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:443)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:525)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:446)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:557)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The Exception will go away if I shut down all connections except a test client.

So, I am wondering if there are any limitations (on the server side) about the MAX numbers of instances of the:

```
io.grpc.ManagedChannel
io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver
```

If there are some, how can I adjust/enlarge them?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `UNKNOWN` status generally means the server failed in some way. You probably want to check the server logs.

There's no real limits to the number of connections and RPCs a server can have. It is possible to run out of file descriptors with too many connections. It is possible to reach RPC limits that would cause them to be queued until they could be sent. And as with anything, you may run into memory usage and similar limits.

Comment: You are correct. The server's failure is caused by something else. I will share the info when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

@Eric is correct. 
Here I just show the problem I met. Hope which can also help others meeting the same problem.

On the server side, I found there are many many Exceptions, such as

```
Apr 19, 2018 5:06:07 PM io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor run
SEVERE: Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1MessagesAvailable@752265fc
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException: Could not return the resource to the pool
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.returnResource(JedisPool.java:256)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.returnResource(JedisPool.java:16)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.close(Jedis.java:3409)
    ...
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler$StreamingServerCallListener.onMessage(ServerCalls.java:251)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.messagesAvailable(ServerCallImpl.java:251)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:592)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getAll(Connection.java:310)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getAll(Connection.java:302)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Pipeline.sync(Pipeline.java:99)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Pipeline.clear(Pipeline.java:85)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.resetState(BinaryJedis.java:1781)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.returnResource(JedisPool.java:252)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Since it mentions the redis, I reviewed the related code, and found that the JedisPoolConfig might not have enough threads, and that the default timeout might be too short.

So I enlarged both, and the problem solved.

In other words, the server does not have enough resources to process the client side requests in a desired time. Which caused the gRPC server to fail, and therefore called the client side onError() methods.

Thank you @Eric.